Flutter: FirebaseStorage upload task is not working, not uploading the image as well
I am trying to capture the image from camera and directly uploading to the Firebase Storage. While doing so I am using upload task. My code is as follows.
UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Suresh.jpg").putFile(picutreFile);
var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
String url = imageUrl.toString();
print(url);

There is no error and the code flow is also fine. But this is not uploading the file to the firebase storage.
This should upload the image file to the firebase Storage

Where is your code that would handle the error if one was thrown?   We can't see that you're handling any errors correctly.  Please edit the question to provide a more complete code sample that anyone can run to see the same result.
